# Use Django authentication from client side DDP Client to access Meteor

Tags: django, meteor, ddp

I am trying to integrate a DDP Client into my Django app  on the client side as explained [here](http://justmeteor.com/blog/wire-up-a-meteor-application-with-an-external-html-page/).

I believe from the post, that everything should work fine, except that I want to add an authentication layer for my publish and subscribe calls. Only a "check" for userLoggedIn to determine if the client is authorized to subscribe is enough.

However, I plan to have the user login done through Django and I want to modify the authentication check in Meteor to use the Django authentication system.

Any idea how I can use the DDP "request" from the DDP client to determine if the user has already been authenticated by Django or not.

I am new to DDP and Django (!) and wondering if there are any session type things in the DDP "request" that I can use on the server side to determine if the user has been authenticated by Django already.

I hope I am able to explain it clearly ... Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I left basically this same response to your question on the django-ddp github page for the same question:

I didn't read that full article, but is the session maintained for each connection on the Django-side? If so, you should be able to just check if the user is authenticated in the normal Django way: for example - request.user.is_authenticated().

On the meteor-side, you may find some clues in the [accounts app](https://github.com/django-ddp/django-ddp/blob/develop/dddp/accounts/ddp.py) included with django-ddp, which emulates the Meteor authentication backend in Django and allows for the auth to occur there. It then sends back the auth token so in Meteor you can check Meteor.user() for the current user as you normally would.

Hopefully that helps...